# How to avoid redirect login.microsoft.com to live.com sign in azure active dirctory

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, office365, azure-active-directory

*Our scenario is* :

we have an application use Microsoft azure AD to authenticate our users. 
all of them use only **organizational** **account**.

*problem*:

After the login request, we arrive into login page(**login.microsoft.com**), after few seconds 
we also redirected automaticaly into **live.com**...

how we can force to use only organizational account,but not microsoft live account or how we can avoid to redirect to live.com...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to restrict logins to only Azure Active Directory based organizational accounts you can pass the following as a query parameter:

msafed=0

If you are using ADAL you can pass this using the extraQueryParameters argument.