# How to block Outlook.com (Microsoft accounts) to login through my Azure AD App

Tags: azure, outlook, single-sign-on, office365, azure-active-directory

I have a web app that is using SSO to login users. I have integrated Microsoft Azure AD to provide SSO to my application. As I have enabled multi-tenancy in Azure AD, users from other domains are able to login without any issue. But it allows the users with Microsoft accounts (like outlook.com) to login to the application.

How to restrict only Office 365 accounts to login to my application?

Comment: related question: [How to avoid redirect login.microsoft.com to live.com sign in azure active directory.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33304001/6224478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can send msafed=0 query parameter to AAD to block MSA users from signing in.